# R: Filter data set for 10 highest means with at least three data points

Tags: r, filter, plot, dataset

I have a big data set and just want to make a boxplot of a small part of it. I only want to plot the columns with the 10 highest means that have at least three data points (because it is a sparse matrix) in descending order.

**Update:** It is not really a sparse matrix. That was just a figure of speech because there are a lot of NAs)

My data set consists of a heading (so named columns) and integer numeric positive values but as I said a lot of NAs.

**Solution:**

With the here provided help and further research I came to the following solution.

```
> barcol<-unlist(sapply(1:N, function(j) sum(!is.na(data[,j]))>2) )
> newdata<-data[,barcol]
> newdata.mean <- colMeans(newdata, na.rm=TRUE)
> newdata.sorted <- newdata[,names(sort(newdata.mean, decreasing=TRUE))]
```

And then the boxplot with a crosshair at the mean.

```
> boxplot(newdata.sorted[,1:10], ylim = c(0, 10))
> points(newdata.mean[1:10], pch = 13)
```

Comment: Please provide a small, reproducible example where you show the code you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: At the very least, what data structure is your data in, maybe a sparse matrix from the `Matrix` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the columns of interest.
EDIT: fixed everything, at last,  I sure hope. For this reduced example, I reject columns with fewer than TWO non-NA values.

```
Rgames> set.seed(1)
Rgames> data<-matrix(NA,4,4)
Rgames> data[sample(1:16,13)]<-sample(10:20,13,rep=TRUE)
Rgames> data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   12   19   17   11
[2,]   16   NA   19   17
[3,]   NA   12   10   12
[4,]   NA   20   14   16
Rgames> barcol<-unlist(sapply(1:4, function(j) sum(!is.na(data[,j]))>2) )   
Rgames> newdata<-data[,barcol]
Rgames> meancol <- order(colMeans(newdata,na.rm=TRUE))
Rgames> newdata
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   19   17   11
[2,]   NA   19   17
[3,]   12   10   12
[4,]   20   14   16
Rgames> meancol
[1] 3 2 1
```

That last result, `meancol`, gives the indices of the three greatest column means, albeit in reverse order.  If you have lots of columns, take the last 10 indices returned by `order`

Comment: OP wants at least 3, so `>2`. Also, I think the parens are unbalanced in you first line: should be `sapply(1:N, ...)`

Comment: Thank you so far. I tried your answer but didn't get very far. Because your first line is missing 2 closing parenthesis I added them at the end. Your 2nd line then produced a data set of the same size but put a copy of one column (that only has 2 entries) in every column. Any idea how to fix your first line?

Comment: @sebastian-- I'll work on fixing at halftime :-)  sorry about the mess.

Comment: great defensive game so far :-). first line should be: `barcol<-unlist(sapply(1:N, function(j) sum(!is.na(data[,j]))>2))` and the last one `meancol <- order(colMeans(newdata, na.rm = TRUE))` to work. And hot do I grab the 10 columns with the highest means to make boxplot?

Comment: @sebastian hope it makes sense now -- hey, were you referring to the S-Hawks' defense, or my quick backtracking on my crummy code? :-)

Comment: It does. Thanks. But `order(colMeans())´ does something weird. `summary(newdata)´ clearly says col1 has the highest mean but ´meancol` says it is at position 34. And a lot of other stuff is also wrong.

Comment: @sebastian  `order` reports the smallest mean first I believe.